# Hierarchical semantic network

Tags: tikz-pgf, context, metapost

I would like to reproduce a hierarquical semantic network like this (Memory and Learning, from brain to behavior", Mark A. Gluck)

[image: Hierarquical semantic network. (Memory and Learning, from brain to behavior, Mark A. Gluck]

My main problem is to add the lateral information in each box. Perhaps, the best way is to write a function in which the arguments should be the box side and the properties list.

My code:

```
\startMPdefinitions
input boxes;
\stopMPdefinitions


\starttext


\startMPcode

%% boxes names
boxit.animal    ("Animal");
boxit.fish        ("Fish");
boxit.bird       ("Bird");
boxit.mammal   ("Mammal");
boxit.canary("Canary");
boxit.ostrich("Ostrich");
boxit.dog("Dog");
boxit.dolphin("dolphin");
boxit.chi("Chihuahua");
boxit.dal("Dalmation");
boxit.fido("Fido");


%% boxes positions

fish.c = origin; 
fish.c = animal.c - 60 up;
animal.c = .5[bird.c,mammal.c] + 60 up; 
bird.c - fish.c= fish.c - mammal.c = 90 left;  
ostrich.c = bird.c + 60 down;
canary.c = ostrich.c + 50 left;
dolphin.c = mammal.c + 20 right + 60 down;
dog.c = dolphin.c + 50 left;
chi.c = dog.c + 50 left + 60 down;
dal.c = dog.c + 50 right + 60 down;
fido.c = dal.c + 60 down;

forsuffixes x = animal, fish, mammal, bird, ostrich, canary, dog, dolphin, chi, dal, fido:
drawboxed(x);
endfor

%%% arrows and paths
path p[];
p1 = animal.sw -- bird.ne;
p2 = animal.s--fish.n;
p3 = animal.se -- mammal.nw;
p4 = bird.s--ostrich.n;
p5 = bird.s--canary.ne;
p6=mammal.s--dog.n;
p7=dog.s--chi.n;
p8=dog.s--dal.n;
p9=dal.s--fido.n;
p10=mammal.s--dolphin.n;

for i=1 upto 10:
drawarrow p[i];
endfor 

\stopMPcode


\stoptext
```

My output:

[image]

Thanks to all

Comment: Do you want this in metapost or tikz/forest? Or both?

Comment: Both, please.  Can arise some beautiful solutions in the tikz side.

Comment: You should post your code as an answer. Right now, it isn't clear to people searching that there are 2 answers and not one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm posting this because you indicated an interest in seeing a TikZ/Forest version. Forest is the most flexible and powerful TikZ-based method to draw trees. However, I'm not sure this is compatible with ConTeXt, even though TikZ itself is. Obviously you would not need `inputenc`, for example, which I'm using here to handle the unicode quotation marks. These could be replaced by TeX mark-up if preferred. I'm just used to typing them this way. But Forest itself seems to be a LaTeX package ....

The tree uses `forest` and the custom format of the tree uses the `backgrounds` TikZ library. Quotation marks are handled here by `csquotes`, but this is obviously optional.

```
\begin{forest}
```

The tree's preamble should be moved into a Forest style if it is to be used for several trees. Here, we simply customise the one particular tree.

```
  for tree={
```

The quoted attributes are not nodes but are added later. So we need to make the tree a bit roomier than it would otherwise be.

```
    fit=band,
    s sep+=20pt,
```

This ensures that when a parent has an odd number of children (e.g. 3), it is aligned with the middle one (e.g. the second).

```
    if={isodd(n_children)}{%
      calign primary child={int((n_children()+1)/2)},
      calign=child,
    }{},
```

Here's our custom edge configuration. The shortening is actually lengthening the lines to compensate for the use of `rounded corners`. To avoid the edges being drawn over the nodes when not draw through a corner, we draw the edges `on background layer`, behind the nodes.

```
    edge={ultra thick, orange!50!yellow, shorten <=-5pt, shorten >=-5pt},
    edge path={%
      \noexpand\scoped[on background layer]
      \noexpand\path [\forestoption{edge}] (!u) -- ()\forestoption{edge label};
    },
```

Custom node configuration with rounded corners, a thick, coloured border and a light fill.

```
    draw=orange!50!yellow,
    rounded corners=5pt,
    ultra thick,
    inner color=orange!75!yellow!10,
    outer color=orange!75!yellow!25,
```

We use sans for the node text and fixed height/depth so that our nodes look nicely aligned.

```
    font=\sffamily,
    text height=2ex,
    text depth=.5ex,
  },
```

This is just a TikZ style, `my pins`, for the quoted bits which is similar to the configuration for the main nodes.

```
  /tikz/my pins/.style={font=\sffamily\footnotesize, text height=1ex, text depth=.25ex, inner sep=1pt},
```

A `right pin` is a custom TikZ node added to the right of one of the main nodes. It takes 2 arguments separated by a colon: `<angle>:<text>`.

```
  right pin/.style args={#1:#2}{%
    tikz+={%
      \scoped[on background layer]\draw [thick, draw=orange!50!yellow, shorten <=-5pt] () -- ++(#1:35pt) node [right, my pins] {‘#2’};
    }
  },
```

`right pins` takes a list of `<angle>:<text>` arguments to be passed to `right pin`.

```
  right pins/.style={%
    split={#1}{,}{right pin}
  },
```

`left pin` and `left pins` are just like `right pin` and `right pins` but, unsurprisingly, for quoted text on the left rather than the right of a main node.

```
  left pin/.style args={#1:#2}{%
    tikz+={%
      \scoped[on background layer]\draw [thick, draw=orange!50!yellow, shorten <=-5pt] () -- ++(#1:35pt) node [my pins, left] {‘#2’};
    }
  },
  left pins/.style={%
    split={#1}{,}{left pin}
  },
```

That's the tree's preamble done. Now for the tree specification, starting with the root node which has 3 attributes quoted to the right. So we use `right pins={:,:,:}.

```
  [Animal, right pins={40:can move,20:eats,0:reproduces}
```

We continue with a node which has 3 attributes quoted to the left by using `left pins` in the same way.

```
    [Bird, left pins={-160:lays eggs,180:is warm-blooded,160:has feathers}
```

The next 2 nodes have 2 `left pins` and 2 `right pins` respectively.

```
      [Canary, left pins={-170:is small,170:works in coal mines}
      ]
      [Ostrich, right pins={-10:cannot fly,10:is quite large}
      ]
    ]
```

We continue, completing and annotating the tree in the same way.

```
    [Fish, right pins={-10:has gills,10:can swim}
    ]
    [Mammal, right pins={-15:has fur,5:produces milk,25:bears live young,45:breathes air}
      [Dog, left pins={170:barks,-170:wags tail}
        [Chihuahua, left pins={-170:is teeny,170:is fierce}
        ]
        [Dalmation, right pins={-10:has 100 siblings,10:is spotted}
          [Fido, right pins={-10:has red kennel,10:is scared of mice}
          ]
        ]
      ]
      [Dolphin, right pins={-10:is highly social,10:lives in pods}
      ]
    ]
  ]
```

Close out the environment

```
\end{forest}
```

and we're done.

[image: semantic network]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz,multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
   \MakeAutoQuote{‘}{’}
   \MakeAutoQuote*{“}{”}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    fit=band,
    s sep+=20pt,
    if={isodd(n_children)}{%
      calign primary child={int((n_children()+1)/2)},
      calign=child,
    }{},
    edge={ultra thick, orange!50!yellow, shorten <=-5pt, shorten >=-5pt},
    edge path={%
      \noexpand\scoped[on background layer]
      \noexpand\path [\forestoption{edge}] (!u) -- ()\forestoption{edge label};
    },
    draw=orange!50!yellow,
    rounded corners=5pt,
    ultra thick,
    inner color=orange!75!yellow!10,
    outer color=orange!75!yellow!25,
    font=\sffamily,
    text height=2ex,
    text depth=.5ex,
  },
  /tikz/my pins/.style={font=\sffamily\footnotesize, text height=1ex, text depth=.25ex, inner sep=1pt},
  right pin/.style args={#1:#2}{%
    tikz+={%
      \scoped[on background layer]\draw [thick, draw=orange!50!yellow, shorten <=-5pt] () -- ++(#1:35pt) node [right, my pins] {‘#2’};
    }
  },
  right pins/.style={%
    split={#1}{,}{right pin}
  },
  left pin/.style args={#1:#2}{%
    tikz+={%
      \scoped[on background layer]\draw [thick, draw=orange!50!yellow, shorten <=-5pt] () -- ++(#1:35pt) node [my pins, left] {‘#2’};
    }
  },
  left pins/.style={%
    split={#1}{,}{left pin}
  },
  [Animal, right pins={40:can move,20:eats,0:reproduces}
    [Bird, left pins={-160:lays eggs,180:is warm-blooded,160:has feathers}
      [Canary, left pins={-170:is small,170:works in coal mines}
      ]
      [Ostrich, right pins={-10:cannot fly,10:is quite large}
      ]
    ]
    [Fish, right pins={-10:has gills,10:can swim}
    ]
    [Mammal, right pins={-15:has fur,5:produces milk,25:bears live young,45:breathes air}
      [Dog, left pins={170:barks,-170:wags tail}
        [Chihuahua, left pins={-170:is teeny,170:is fierce}
        ]
        [Dalmation, right pins={-10:has 100 siblings,10:is spotted}
          [Fido, right pins={-10:has red kennel,10:is scared of mice}
          ]
        ]
      ]
      [Dolphin, right pins={-10:is highly social,10:lives in pods}
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a usefully and great solution, tanks a lot. The explanation is also great.  I need to make some minor changes, because i use Context. Now, with this approach, is very easy for me to make all the diagrams that i need to do. Thanks again and have a nice day.

Comment: I'm glad it is useful! I wasn't sure because I don't know ConTeXt and I feared it might not be usable. I'm pleased to hear that's not the case :).

Answer (score 2):

After cfr suggestion I post my own code because Tikz/forest don't works in ConteXt. The function pins(box name)(left "e" or right "d")("characteristic  one","characteristic two", ...) do the job.

```
\startMPdefinitions
input boxes;
\stopMPdefinitions


\starttext


\startMPcode

% best guess at the required colors
color mid_blue, dark_blue, laranja, dentro, fora;
mid_blue  = (79/255, 129/255, 189/255); 
dark_blue = (56/255,  93/255, 138/255);
laranja=(1,0.6,0);
dentro = .75*laranja + .10*yellow;
fora = .75*laranja + .25*yellow;

%% boxes names
boxit.animal    ("Animal");
boxit.fish        ("Peixe");
boxit.bird       ("Ave");
boxit.mammal   ("Mamífero");
boxit.canary("Canário");
boxit.ostrich("Avestruz");
boxit.dog("Cão");
boxit.dolphin("Golfinho");
boxit.chi("Chihuahua");
boxit.dal("Dálmata");
boxit.fido("Aika");


%% boxes positions

fish.c = origin; 
fish.c = animal.c - 40 up;
animal.c = .5[bird.c,mammal.c] + 40 up; 
bird.c - fish.c= fish.c - mammal.c = 130 left;  
ostrich.c = bird.c + 40 down;
canary.c = ostrich.c + 70 left;
dolphin.c = mammal.c + 30 right + 40 down;
dog.c = dolphin.c + 75 left;
chi.c = dog.c + 60 left + 40 down;
dal.c = dog.c + 60 right + 40 down;
fido.c = dal.c + 40 down;

forsuffixes x = animal, fish, mammal, bird, ostrich, canary, dog, dolphin, chi, dal, fido:
  x.ne-x.sw = (60,20); 

  fill bpath x withcolor fora;
  draw pic   x withcolor  \MPcolor{darkred};
  draw bpath x withcolor dentro;

endfor

%%% arrows and paths
path p[];
p1 = animal.sw -- bird.ne;
p2 = animal.s--fish.n;
p3 = animal.se -- mammal.nw;
p4 = bird.s--ostrich.n;
p5 = bird.s--canary.ne;
p6=mammal.s--dog.n;
p7=dog.s--chi.n;
p8=dog.s--dal.n;
p9=dal.s--fido.n;
p10=mammal.s--dolphin.n;

%%%%
def pins(suffix caixa)(expr local)(text thelabels) =
      pair pos[]; 
      string name[], sitio; 
      if local="d":
      pos1=caixa.e;
      pos2=caixa.se; pos3=caixa.ne;
      else:
      pos1=caixa.w;
      pos3=caixa.sw; pos2=caixa.nw;
      fi;

      path cami, lixo;
      cami := pos3 -- pos2;
      k:= 0; for t = thelabels: k := k+1; name[k] = t; endfor
      for i = 1 upto k:
          pos4 := (i/(k+1))[pos2,pos3];
          pos5 := pos4 if local="d": + else: - fi (20, i*2);
         label.if local="d": rt else: lft fi(textext(name[i]) scaled .5, pos5);
         draw pos4 -- pos5; 
      endfor;
enddef;


drawoptions(withpen pencircle scaled 1 pt withcolor mid_blue);
for i=1 upto 10:
draw p[i];
endfor 

pins(animal)("d")("Come","Move-se", "Reproduz-se");
pins(bird)("e")("tem asas","pode voar", "põe ovos");
pins(mammal)("d")("respira ar","produzem leite","têm pele");
pins(dolphin)("d")("vivem na água","têm barbatanas");
pins(dal)("d")("têm pontos negros","máscote dos bombeiros");
pins(fido)("d")("animal de estimação","gosta de doces");
pins(chi)("e")("é castanho","é pequeno");
pins(dog)("e")("tem pelo","têm cauda");
pins(canary)("e")("é amarelo","canta");
pins(ostrich)("d")("não voa","é grande");
pins(fish)("e")("vive na água","têm cauda");

\stopMPcode


\stoptext
```

the output:

[image]
Thanks to all